# Down key suddenly stopped working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard

I currently have Ubuntu 20.04 in a lenovo thinkpat T440P, it has been working flawlessy until now. The arrow down key suddenly stopped responding.

I cant scroll and need help figuring it out.

Comment: its probably (almost certainly) a problem on your keyboard and not on Ubuntu

Comment: In browsers space is generally "scroll down one page" when outside a text input, and pgup/pgdn should go up and down normally in most programs. The key may just need cleaning, or it could be worn down depending on the internals of the keyboard, or just broken. You can attempt to check if it's been remapped by opening a terminal and entering `Ctrl-v` and then pressing the down key and editing the output of that into your question. If it's not remapped or doesn't even work then it's probably dirty, worn, or broken.